# Silverlight Focus() then Command Call = Fail?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, focus

Im having problems when calling a command right after the Focus() call. The command doesn't seem to use the good values I typed into the textbox. It uses the value that was there BEFORE I changed the value (sync issue)

p.s.: I just call btnArrow.Focus(); to make the textbox i'm typing in lose its focus.

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    { if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { btnArrow.Focus(); btnArrow.Command.Execute(null); });
            (sender as Control).Focus();
        }}
```

The only way I managed to make it work is with a Thread like this (OMG ugLY I know!)

```
 if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            btnArrow.Focus();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            btnArrow.Command.Execute(null);
            (sender as Control).Focus();
        }
```

My goal is just to have the command called with the good textbox values.

I've tried KeyUp event too... Am I missing something?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your TextBox.Text binding is TwoWay:

```
    private void JTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // option 1 - pass the value in
            JButton.Command.Execute(JTextBox.Text); 

            // option 2 - force the binding
            JTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            JButton.Command.Execute(null); 
        }
    }
```

Although I'd like to hear about any pitfalls with option 2...